# Prevent "24" value of hour in a time (without seconds)

Tags: java

I've had a request to code a method which will do pretty much a basic time validation.
Time must fall into an interval : 00:00-23:59, and no seconds. Actually seconds are forbidden.
I'm interested in a solution which uses Java 8 date/time api (if there is one).

Because I haven't found one, I came up with this solution :

```
private void validateTimeWithoutSeconds(String timeValue) throws Exception {
    boolean hasSeconds = false;
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss").parse(timeValue);
        hasSeconds = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    if (hasSeconds) {
        String err1 = "\Error : Time has seconds.";
        throw new Exception(err1);
    }

    try {
        LocalTime.parse(timeValue, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String err2 = "Error. Time does not belong to the interval of 00:00-23:59";
        throw new Exception(err2);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you expect the format to be HH:mm, why do you parse with HH:mm:ss, or with ISO_TIME, and not with HH:mm?

Comment: Just use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").parse(timeValue);`

Comment: (Follow-up: Why mix DateTimeFormatter.parse and LocalTime.parse?)

Comment: Why not simply parse the string to integers by splitting the string at ':' and do your validations?

Comment: Unfortunately, "DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").parse(24:00);" does not throw exception. I've already tried that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution for this with string regular expression as you input is in string I would say it is a better approach . Use below example:

`timeValue.matches("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]")`.

Comment: it's always useful to see regex and thanks for that.
I just wondered if there is a clean and short solution like yours, but using java 8 date/time api

Answer (score 2):

You have discovered a mystery.

- A custom formatting pattern of `HH:mm` allows `24:00` as a valid value.
- Using the pre-defined formatter [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME) does not accept 24:00 and throws a `DateTimeParseException`.

This formatter accepts `24:00` as `00:00`:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm" ); // Accepts 24:00 as meaning 00:00.
```

Wheras, this built-in formatter throws an exception when encountering `24:00`:

```
 DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME ;  // Expects 00:00 to 23:59.
```

Letting `HH:mm` allow `24:00` violates [the class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), and seems to doing the job of `kk:mm`:

> k  clock-hour-of-day (1-24)    number  24
>
> H  hour-of-day (0-23)  number  0

I suggest you submit a bug report. I am seeing the same behavior as you while using Java 10.0.2 on the OpenJDK-based Zulu JVM from Azul Systems, running on a MacBook Pro Retina using macOS High Sierra. And IdeOne.com exhibits the same behavior running Java 8.

## Workaround: Use default formatter rather than define your own

First of all, if only hours & minutes are allowed, but no seconds, [check the length](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()).

```
if( input.length() >  5 ) { … }  // Valid input such as `12:34` has maximum length of five characters.
```

Otherwise, parse the input string using the built-in formatter, [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME).

Trap for the *specific* exception you expect with invalid input: [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```
String input = "24:00";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME ;  // Expects 00:00 to 23:59. Throws a `DateTimeParseException` with `24:00` input.
LocalTime lt;
try {
    lt = LocalTime.parse( input , f );
    System.out.println( lt );
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {   // Invalid input.
    System.out.println( "Invalid input." );
} catch ( Exception e ) {                // Something else went wrong.
    System.out.println( "Something else went wrong." );
}
```

An input of `24:00` throws the exception as we expect:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '24:00' could not be parsed: Invalid value for HourOfDay (valid values 0 - 23): 24

By the way, rather than reject an input with seconds, you may choose to [truncate the seconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "12:34:56" ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ) ; // Lop off any seconds or fractional second. Returns value in whole minutes.
```

> lt.toString(): 12:34

Comment: I don't have exception as you do. That's the whole mystery.

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
String v = "24:00";
        try {
            LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(v, f);
            System.err.println("v : " + lt.format(f));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException е1) {
            System.err.println("greška : " + е1.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception е2) {
            System.err.println("greška : " + е2.getMessage());
        }

output is :
v : 00:00

Comment: @dobrivoje Indeed, I see your mystery now. Your pasted [code runs live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nPkJ8q) without throwing the exception. Defining a formatting pattern of `HH:mm` is behaving differently than [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME). I have no idea why.

Comment: @dobrivoje I have fixed my Answer now. Originally I did not run my posted code example, and unwittingly tested the default formatter used by `LocalTime.parse`. I apologize for misleading you with incorrect information.

Comment: Thanks. That's it : DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME validates time correctly, whereas DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm") does not.
Actually, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME correctly parses both with seconds and without and odes not allow 24 to appear as input.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, create your pattern with `withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)`. When creating a new pattern, the default is `ResolverStyle.SMART`, which does some basic guessing for out of range numbers.

Regarding `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` mentioned in another answer, it uses `STRICT`, which is why there is different behavior for seemingly the same pattern (the pattern *is* the same, but the resolver style is different). From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME:):

> The returned formatter has no override chronology or zone. It uses the `STRICT` resolver style.

The confusion comes from that it seems unexpected that the built-in constant patterns use `STRICT` whereas custom patterns default to `SMART`.

More info about the different resolver styles: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html